# Limit various checkbox inside different classes independently

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, each

I'm a novice with JS and jQuery and i'm facing a problem that i cannot solve with my knowledge...
I have a site that lets users select different types of salads with different options, but i need to limit the choices of some items and i don't know how to do it.
The checkboxes resides inside a class, but i have too many of them and i just wanted to limit the ones that are in a particular class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#dressing-1 input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
                if($('#dressing-1 input[type=checkbox]:checked').length>=2){
                    alert($('#dressing-1 input[type=checkbox]:checked').length);
                    $('#dressing-1 input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').prop("disabled", true);
                } else {
                    $('#dressing-1 input[type=checkbox]').prop("disabled", false);
                }
            });
    });
```

This is the code that i have right now and it's working, but just for the first item. I would like to make this code available to all of the items with the class `.contenido-dressign` and for now i'm using the id `#dressing-1` just to corroborates that it works well.
The idea is to make a more *elegant* code instead of using #dressing-1 #dressing-2.. etc... that's why i'm trying to apply this to the container `.contenido-dressing`.

This is the site: [lunchtime.cl/menu](http://lunchtime.cl/menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `this` in your function click refer to the checkbox itsefl, so it doesnt call all of the checkbox. do something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.contenido-dressing').find(':checkbox').change(function(){
        var parent = $(this).parent()
        if(parent.find(':checked').length >= 2){
            parent.find(':checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            parent.find(':checkbox').attr('disabled', false );
        }
    });
});
```

Don't need each function, you bind all checkbox who's into div `.contenigo-dressing` and find his parent.

Here a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SyZ9Z/

Comment: sorry, but it didn't worked. I updated the code if you're interested in it. I'm still cannot achieve what i want, at least not in an "elegant coded" way.

Comment: ok, I checked my code and I just forgot to put a `false` somewhere. I updated my answer with a fiddle and now it's working. I also changed the `click` binding for `change`.

Answer (score 0):

"this" is an object not a string

use something like

```
$('[type=checkbox]', this)
```

Also checkbox is not being clicked, the label is.

my suggestion:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.contenido-dressing').each(function(){
        var $c;
        $c = $('[type=checkbox]', this);

        $c.change(function(){
            if($c.filter(":checked").size() >= 2){
                $c.filter(":not(:checked)").attr('disabled', true);
            } else {
                $c.attr('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Update:**
even shorter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.contenido-dressing').each(function(){
        var $c;
        $c = $('[type=checkbox]', this);

        $c.change(function(){
            $c.filter(":not(:checked)")
              .attr('disabled', ($c.filter(":checked").size() >= 2));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but that didn't worked. I updated the code. It's working now, but only for the first container. I would like to do that to all the .contenido-dressing classes but i can't.

Comment: Oh, it's because $c was getting overwritten each time.
The line "var $c;" solves the issue.